# How to run a fish alias from cron?

Tags: cron, fish

I have set up a fish alias for some commands that I frequently need to run manually. Now, I want the same commands to be run regularly. How can I set up `cron` to automatically run a fish alias?

Comment: Write the alias as a script instead and then schedule the script?

Answer (score 0):

A possible way is to put the following in the `crontab`:

```
* * * * * user fish -c "my-fish-alias"
```

One has to make sure that the aliases are defined for the user that runs the cron job, e.g. by putting the `my-fish-alias.fish` file that defines the alias in `/etc/fish/functions`.